# Assigning different RndNum w/o repeats to range of cells in Excel with VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

So this is the code I have so far and it gives me a random number that will not repeat but I do not know how to get it to apply a different number to a range of cells:

```
Sub proces_randomizer()
    Const NUM = 18
    Dim iloop As Integer
    Dim Array1() As Integer
    Dim Already_Picked() As Boolean
    Dim Random_Number As Integer

    ReDim Array1(1 To NUM)
    ReDim Already_Picked(1 To NUM)

    For iloop = 1 To NUM
        Do
            Random_Number = (((NUM - 1) * Rnd) + 1)
        Loop Until Not (Already_Picked(Random_Number))
        Array1(iloop) = Random_Number
        Already_Picked(Random_Number) = True

        Range("B1", "B18").Value = Random_Number

    Next iloop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question and copy/paste your code inside.

Comment: @Grant Nichols, RANDBETWEEN and assign to a range with decimals ? That should always give you different numbers. And why from code, you could drag RAND formula in worksheet too ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the line saying `Range("B1", "B18").Value = Random_Number` (which was saying to set every cell in `B1:B18` to the current number.
2. Insert a line after your `Next iloop` statement which says

   ```
   Range("B1:B18").Value = Application.Transpose(Array1)
   'or perhaps even
   Range("B1:B" & NUM).Value = Application.Transpose(Array1)
   ```

   which will copy the contents of your array (containing each individual random number) to `B1:B18`.